# How to remove extra animation actions in blender?

Tags: animation, customization, actions, settings

I usually make extra actions accidently. and the problem is that they always make my project untidy and I don't know how to delete 'em.[image]

I searched in google but I didn't find any good way for doing this.

I already checked out Edit/Preferences window but I didn't find anything for deleting actions.

Comment: Go to the action editor. Use the dropdown menu to select the action.  Make sure the 'shield' is not checked, and click the x to delete, iirc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Outliner, click on the <kbd>Display Mode</kbd> icon (1 below) then on the <kbd>Orphan Data</kbd> entry (2).
[image]

Expand the <kbd>Actions</kbd> entry and you'll see your list of actions with a <kbd>0</kbd> against any which aren't used. You can then right-click on the unwanted ones and delete them using <kbd>X</kbd>.

[image]